# Why is there no Reputation for Badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, badges

Like the title says, why is there no Reputation for Badges?

When I achieve all I get is that if someone goes on my profile they can see that I earned that badge but you really do not get anything else than that.

So this comes down to why do you earn reputation and does a badge fit that reason.

(I am asking this question because I thought about why something gains you reputation and I think that badges fit that slot)

Comment: This would be a much stronger question if you would include what exactly you mean by "reputation for badges" as well as a compelling case for it to be so.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certain gold badges *do* give you more abilities. If you have a gold badge in a tag, and a question is asked with that tag as one of the original tags, you can mark it as a duplicate with a single vote. The theory behind it is, if you've got a gold badge in a particular tag, you know the content well *within* that tag and are likely to know where things have been asked before and how.

We're looking into other ways that badges can unlock additional 'special' abilities at the higher level. I don't think we'd ever flat out grant a pocket-shot of reputation with one, but making the difficult to earn badges a bit more desirable to earn (or something more exciting beyond 'neat, that happened, yay') is definitely on the table.

Answer (score 4):

Reputation is for contributing content that others find useful.  Mostly this comes from good questions and answers; it can also come from edits that get approved, and on rare occasions somebody values an answer so much that he awards an extra bounty.

Badges are lightweight.  Some recognize achievements for which you've already earned reputation -- Mortarboard for hitting the daily reputation cap, Nice/Good/Great Answer/Question for achieving certain scores, and a few others.  Most badges, though, are just "attaboys" for doing things that help the site in other ways -- voting, flagging, reviewing posts, participating on meta, and so on.  While we are a Q&A site, we are not *just* a Q&A site that operates on its own; we need the community to participate in other ways too, and badges recognize that.

While people only see *which* badges you've earned by going to your profile (much as they only see *how* you earned reputation by going there), *how many*
badges of each type appears under your name and rep on all your posts.  So badges are not invisible.

Comment: I understand your point but I still disagree, but even according to your opinion that holds that it helps the community but since it does not help others we do not give reputation. Wouldn't be better if you would have reputation for badges so more people would want to achieve them?

Comment: Badges are second-tier; they're an extra thing that Stack Exchange added to provide another dimension of user recognition.  I don't see value in fuzzing this line by awarding reputation for them too; that seems to devalue reputation.  But feel free to make a case for it in a feature request!  (You tagged this both "discussion" and "feature request"; I answered it as a discussion question, "why is it this way?".)